# C3 stacked column chart from CSV

Tags: csv, charts, c3

I would like to create a stacked bar chart in C3 but reading in CSV with url: "data.csv"

I am not sure if that functionality exists or if I need to convert the CSV in JSON for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert. C3 supports this.

From the example at http://c3js.org/samples/data_url.html

> ```
>  var chart = c3.generate({
>     data: {
>         url: '/data/c3_test.csv'
>     } 
>  });
> ```